# BASH get error code in parent terminal from child terminal?

Tags: bash, process, parent-child, error-code, gnome-terminal

In a bash script I start a new terminal with a command that gives an error. However I don't seem to be able to grab that error code:

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cat dksdamfasdlm"
echo $?
```

Output:

```
0
```

So I get the error code of the `gnome-terminal` command instead of the `cat` one. One suggestion I got, was to make a file with the code and read that from the parent bash. The problem is that I still seem to not be able and read the error code even that way:

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cat dksdamfasdlm; echo $?; sleep 2"
```

Output (on new terminal):

```
cat: dksdamfasdlm: No such file or directory
0
```

Why is that? Some suggestion on how to solve this? I just want to somehow grab the error in the new terminal from the parent bash.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Unless you're testing GNOME Terminal itself, you should be running the script directly rather than through a terminal.

Comment: I am trying to make a BASH script that opens different terminals for an application(Docker). I however want to be able and catch any errors..

Comment: Could you give a bit more background? I still don't understand why you want to use terminals rather than just running scripts.

Comment: Well it's a complicated scenario. I want to run this script from a terminal. The script is supposed to open a new terminal which will connect to a running VM. The parent terminal is then supposed to also connect to the VM. If however the launched terminal couldn't successfully connect to the VM, then the script should exit immediately instead of also trying to connect to the VM.

Comment: You could just background the first connection, then you can do both connections in the same script without spawning a separate terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **GNOME Terminal exits immediately after starting**, which is obvious if you run for example `gnome-terminal -x sleep 10`. Since it doesn't wait for the command to finish, there's no way the return code will be that of the command. I could find no option in `gnome-terminal --help-all` to keep the process in the foreground.

Regarding your second question, you've double-[quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the command, so `$?` is expanded *before* running it. This should work:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'cat dksdamfasdlm; echo $?; sleep 2'
```

PS: The `-x` option is not documented in GNOME Terminal 3.8.4's `gnome-terminal --help-all`, [various](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal) [references](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) don't help much, and there's no good explanation for why there's a `-e` option with identical semantics and different syntax.